# Select A Hidden Panel Button After Press Return Button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

I'm working on a Menu in Unity with several buttons. How could I make pressing the "Return" button on the keyboard automatically select another button?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Input.GetKeyDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) in your update method to check if the return key has been pressed.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
    {
        // Return key pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: Tks for your answer. In fact, that wasn't quite what I wanted.

When pressing the keyboard ENTER key, the hidden panel opens and I would like to automatically select the YES button.